# input(), raw_input(), echoing input as asterisks

Tags: python

Is there a way to protect user input by echoing asterisks ?

Or do i need to look at a different approach and use something aside from input().

Seems sloppy to have the user enter in their credentials without some rudimentary protection or 
consideration.

When using getpass I am then unable to authenticate to gmail.

Are there other considerations or some "unpacking" that needs to be done with pass=getpass.getpass('enter password')?

Comment: LMGTFY: http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html

Comment: *“Are there other considerations or some ‘unpacking’ that needs to be done”* – No, `getpass` returns a string. You can print it out to check if the input was correct. Otherwise something else is failing.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [getpass module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html).

```
import getpass
mypass = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password:")
```

This does not echo the asterisks, but it does hide your typing, which is presumably the goal.

Comment: `getpass()` does *not* display asterisks instead of the actual keypresses.