# Python. How to replace input with asterisks

Tags: python, passwords

I need help with a password issue.

I'm trying to create a simple password program, but the problem I am having is that I cannot replace the input with '*'s  without importing anything.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533539/input-raw-input-echoing-input-as-asterisks

Comment: If you really don't want to import a module, You might want to copy the code of the getpass.getpass function, you can find it in the python directory

Answer (score 3):

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```

*Note that getpass is a part of the standard library.*

But if you are not doing **any** imports then you have a big problem as the only other ways all involve control of the terminal such as getting each key and replacing the output with * but that sort of control of the terminal is itself an import.

Comment: I don't think that the question asker wants to use a module

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't do imports, then do this:

Enter the python directory in your computer, search for the getpass module, open the source code and search for the getpass function/class/whatever, copy-paste It in your code, Done.